# How do I select a random array, and then a random index inside THAT array?

Tags: arrays, random, return, arguments, autohotkey

```
;Sayings
friendly := ["hello there!", "Howdy!", "Greetings friend!", "hi there"]
helpful := ["x next to y and z", "this is helpful", "The sky is blue"]
other := ["where is my toaster", "do it", "just"]

;Categories
welcome := [[friendly][helpful][other]]

Numpad0::
    intotext(randomfromarray("friendly"),50,35,15)
    return

Numpad1::
    intotext(randomfromarray("helpful"),50,35,15)
    return

;Numpad2::
    ;Select a random saying from the welcome category.

intotext(whatisit,thekeydelay,introwait,outrowait)
{
    SetKeyDelay, thekeydelay
    Send, t
    Sleep, %introwait%  
    Send, %whatisit% 
    Sleep, %outrowait%
    Send, {enter}
}

randomfromarray(uniquepickof){
    return %uniquepickof%[random(1, %uniquepickof%.maxindex() )]
}

random(x, y){
   Random, var, %x%, %y%
   return var
}
```

1. Can someone help me figure out (for Numpad2::) how to select a random Sayings array from the Welcome category, and then select a random index of that (saying) array?

I tried throwing a few ideas down but they all resulted with only "t" because I did not return the (pick random array )[index] value properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I got to work:

```
;Sayings
friendly := ["hello there!", "Howdy!", "Greetings friend!", "hi there"]
helpful := ["x next to y and z", "this is helpful", "The sky is blue"]
other := ["where is my toaster", "do it", "just"]

;Categories
welcome := [friendly, helpful, other]

Random, randNumOne, 1, welcome.MaxIndex()

MsgBox % "Your random number is for array is: " . randNumOne

randArray := welcome[randNumOne]

Random, randNumTwo, 1, randArray.MaxIndex()

MsgBox %  "Your random Saying is " . randArray[randNumTwo]
```

To simplify, I removed your custom function that was really just a wrapper around the built-in `Random` function. I left the MsgBox so that you can verify the output as being random.

Here's your entire script with the new random select function assigned to Numpad2 keypress:

```
;Sayings
friendly := ["hello there!", "Howdy!", "Greetings friend!", "hi there"]
helpful := ["x next to y and z", "this is helpful", "The sky is blue"]
other := ["where is my toaster", "do it", "just"]

;Categories
welcome := [friendly, helpful, other]

Numpad0::
    intotext(randomfromarray("friendly"),50,35,15)
    return

Numpad1::
    intotext(randomfromarray("helpful"),50,35,15)
    return

Numpad2::
    Random, randNumOne, 1, welcome.MaxIndex()

    MsgBox % "Your random number is for array is: " . randNumOne

    randArray := welcome[randNumOne]

    Random, randNumTwo, 1, randArray.MaxIndex()

    MsgBox %  "Your random Saying is " . randArray[randNumTwo]
    return

intotext(whatisit,thekeydelay,introwait,outrowait)
{
    SetKeyDelay, thekeydelayt
    Send, t
    Sleep, %introwait%  
    Send, %whatisit% 
    Sleep, %outrowait%
    Send, {enter}
}

randomfromarray(array)
{
    Random, rand, 1, array.MaxIndex()

    return array[rand]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified a few things and added a (category) arg to the randomfromarray and with an if statement returned randarray[randsaying].

 if cat {
  Random, rand1, 1, %unique%.maxIndex()
  randArray := %unique%[rand1]
  Random, randSaying, 1, randArray.MaxIndex() 
  return randArray[randSaying]
 }

Comment: That's great! I have a sort of off topic question about your code: what's up with the `intotext` function you have? It was doing some pretty odd things when I was working on the script so I had to comment it out til I finished

Comment: intotext is a function to type the selected saying into a text box for a game, the hotkey to open the chatbox being the sent "t", and the wait times for latency.